# Semaphore NodeJS endless loading page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, infinite-loop, semaphore

i'm writing a program that when a client joins to "/json", it gives you a json. I want to adjust this with a semaphore where 1 client per time requests the resource and if it's changed, then it gives to you. I'm using a package in npm called "semaphore" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/semaphore).

```
kasRouter.get(path + '/json',(req,res)=>{
    sem.take(async () => {
        let toggle2 = await utils.getToggleKas()
        console.log(req)
        if(toggle2 != toggle){
            sem.leave()
            toggle = toggle2
            console.log(toggle)
            res.json({
                'kas':toggle
            })
        }
    })
})
```

as you can see, when the client joins in the path, i use sem.take() function to let the client wait for leaving it. toggle and toggle2 are basically 2 vars that take a boolean in the json (in a database). When the main route starts the first toggle gets the boolean and when the client joins in the json path waits for toggle chages. The problem in this code is that client tries infinit endlessly to connect in the page but without a response from the server.

Comment: btw i'm sure that this bool changes in the db

Comment: I assume you already have `var sem = require('semaphore')(1)` and also have `sem.leave()` OUTSIDE of the `if statement` so that it's always cleared after request

Comment: yes, i have them

Comment: according to your code.. `sem.leave` is called only **inside** the if statement, which means that only when `utils.getToggleKas` changes, it will return a new request, else you would NEVER return anything, and that's why if you make a request, if no change has been made since the last request, you will not get any data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you seem to be missing some things. Namely, you don't call `res.end` and `sem.leave` is only called if the result from `await utils.getToggleKas()` changes

See if the code snippet below helps

```js
kasRouter.get(path + '/json',(req,res)=>{
    sem.take(async () => {
        let toggle2 = await utils.getToggleKas()
        console.log(req)
        if(toggle2 != toggle){
            toggle = toggle2
            console.log(toggle)
            res.json({
                'kas':toggle
            })
        }
        sem.leave() //after every requests, leaves it for a new one
    })
    //res.end() //ends the request in case this doesn't happen elsewhere
    //see if commenting this out ends the problem?
})
```

Comment: it throws me ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err), while i try to update the page

Comment: why do i have to unlock it when they are equal?

Comment: so, let's say you load the site and the `await utils.getToggleKas()` is `["a", "b", "c"]` and you load it, then you reload it.. if the `await utils.getToggleKas()` is still `["a", "b", "c"]`, it will never load